Binding data in SAP Build Apps
I want to create a test app in SAP Build Apps but I'm getting no data into my list items. The connection to my OData service works.
Is it normal, that the response is in "responseText"?

This is my workflow. I want to store the data in the page variable "employees":

This is my list. I want to bind it to "employees". Is the binding correct?

This is the result:

